# Why is onSelectionChange called twice?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular Material Autocomplete as follows:

```xml
<mat-autocomplete #autocomplete="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" autoActiveFirstOption>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions$ | async" [value]="option" (onSelectionChange)="onSelectionChanged(option)" >
    {{displayFn(option)}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

This is the handler:

```
onSelectionChanged(option) {
  console.log('Selected ' + option.name);
}
```

For some reason `onSelectionChanged()` gets called twice. The second time with the **old** value! I don't get why. What is happenning here?

Selecting item 1 and then item 2 and then item 3 will print:

```
> Selected item 1
> Selected item 2
> Selected item 1  // The unwanted call with the old value
> Selected item 3
> Selected item 2  // The unwanted call with the old value
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

material has optionSelected event you can use it

```xml
<mat-autocomplete #autocomplete="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onSelectionChanged($event)" [displayWith]="displayFn" autoActiveFirstOption>
 <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions$ | async" [value]="option" >
    {{displayFn(option)}}
 </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

and get your value that way

```
onSelectionChanged(event) {
   console.log(event.option.value);
}
```

Comment: This was driving me crazy ^^ Thanks

Comment: the problem that i am having is that the options are collection of objects (with id and name). if i put id as value, then on select it shows to the user the selected id on screen. if i put the name as value then the event gives me the name and not id. how do i solve this

Answer (score 36):

I was facing the same problem for a **mat-option** inside a **mat-select** and fixed this way:

**Template**

```xml
<mat-select>
 <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="handleMetaSignalChange(metaSignal.name,$event);" *ngFor="let metaSignal of metaSignals" [value]="metaSignal">
  {{ metaSignal.name }}
 </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**Code**

```
 handleMetaSignalChange(metaSignal: string, event: any) {
    if (event.isUserInput) {    // ignore on deselection of the previous option
      console.log('Meta Signal Changed to ' + metaSignal + event.isUserInput);
    }
 }
```

Comment: BEST SOLUTION. I needed to get the whole object of the (OnSelectionChange) to use its children values like countryCode, countryName, and countryFlag. This issue took a whole  day of mine. Thanks for sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 11):

**If you need to get the whole OBJECT and use its children values in the component:**

1- Send both **object** and **$event** from DOM to component.ts.

```
<!-- Printing out the country name and flag only -->

 <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
   <mat-option 
      *ngFor="let country of filteredCountries$ | async" 
      [value]="country.name"
      (onSelectionChange)="getSelectedCountry(country, $event)">
      <img class="example-option-img" aria-hidden [src]="country.flag" height="25">
      <span>{{country.name}}</span>
   </mat-option>
 </mat-autocomplete>
```

2- Now update your values in the component.ts

```
getSelectedCountry(country: ICountry, event: any): void {
   if (event.isUserInput) {    // ignore on deselection of the previous option
     console.log("Selected country name: ", country.name);
     console.log("Selected country code: ", country.code);
     console.log("Selected country flag link: ", country.flag);
}
```

Note: *ICountry* is my country Interface which is not required to have.

Comment: +1 for 

if (event.isUserInput) {}

Answer (score 8):

As noted in [this issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7851), this is the expected behavior of onSelectionChanged. A selection change event is fired not only when an option is selected but also when it is deselected. So when an option is selected, the event fires on it, and also on any option that is deselected.

Try using [optionSelected](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api) instead.

Answer (score 5):

Just used (click) instead. Take a look:

```
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option
      (click)="selected(entity)"
      *ngFor="let entity of filteredOptions"
      [value]="entity.short"
    >
      {{ entity.short_header}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
```

Edit: This won't be triggered if you use the keyboard to select the option.
So, alternatively as you already use [displayWith], the value will be the object. and you can use the (optionSelected) output on the mat-autocomplete element:

```
<mat-autocomplete (optionSelected)="optionSelected($event)" 
#auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayEntity">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let e of filteredEntities$ | async" [value]="e">
        {{ e.short_header }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the user selects an option using their keyboard.

Comment: That's right, that's why I added the update (Edit)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the explanation. My case was different so I shared what worked for me as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can check if event was triggered by user as follows:

```
//.html 
 <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions$ | async" [value]="option" (onSelectionChange)="onSelectionChanged($event)" >


//.ts
onSelectionChanged(option) {
   if(option.isUserInput==true){
      console.log('Selected ' + option.name);
   }
}
```

Comment: No such property

Comment: @YasarArafath have you passed the $event variable to this method in html file?

Answer (score 1):

HTML WITH MATERIAL TEMPLATE: This is selection it uses onSelectionChange, but it is called twice in the select, so passing the $event object to the change() method, then allows the isUserInput attribute to determine if the event has fired already, and perform the statements within it only once.  This select works well within a mat-table.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="version">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Version</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-select [(value)]="selected[i].name">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of mySelectArray;" 
        [value]="item.name" (onSelectionChange)="change(i, $event, item);">
          {{item.id}}&nbsp;{{item.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

IN THE TYPESCRIPT: This change method, has the event.isUserInput which determines whether the event has already fired, thus prohibiting it from executing that change again. I hope this helps, SNIFF.

```
change(i: number, event, item: {id: number, name: string, value: string, type: string}) {
    if (event.isUserInput) {
      this.myTableDtoArray[i] = item;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<myTableDto>(this.myTableDtoArray);
      this.dataSource._updateChangeSubscription;
      console.log(this.myTableDtoArray[i], item);
    }
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it using as follows:

1. Material way:

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage" (ngModelChange)="onLangChange($event)">
                                            <mat-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language">
                                                {{language}}
                                            </mat-option>
                                        </mat-select>
```

2. Traditional way:

```
   <select [(ngModel)]="status" (ngModelChange)="onChangeStatus($event)"
                                                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                                                class="form-control custom-select" id="status">
                                                <option i18n value="All" selected>Statut</option>
                                                <option i18n value="Yes">Visible</option>
                                                <option i18n value="No">Non Visible</option>
                                            </select>
```

In your component ts file:

```
onChangeStatus(event) {
    if (event === "All") {
      this.status = ...
    }
    else
     ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use (change) event

```
<mat-autocomplete #autocomplete="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" autoActiveFirstOption>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions$ | async" [value]="option" (change)="onSelectionChanged(option)" >
    {{displayFn(option)}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
changeDegree(event) {
    if (event.isUserInput) { 
      console.log(event.source.value);

      this._degreeArray.length = 0;
      this.changeDegreeDetails(event.source.value.id);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted this under the right question? In any case, you should explain how this code solves the problem in the question.